# How do I get glass walls without borders?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I place glass walls, it shows the outline of every glass block. I see you-tubers like [DanTDM](https://www.youtube.com/user/TheDiamondMinecart) or [PopularMMOs](https://www.youtube.com/user/PopularMMOs) have glass walls that look like one big glass block, with no block outlines. How do I get the glass without outlines?

Answer (score 11):

I assume you mean something like this:

[image]

AFAIK, you can only do this with a mod called [Optifine](http://optifine.net/home):

1. Close Minecraft and the Launcher.
2. Go to the [download page](http://optifine.net/downloads.php) and download Optifine HD Ultra for the MC version you are using.
3. Open the `.jar` file you just downloaded (using java!) and click install.

When it is finished, close that and open Minecraft. There should be a profile called "Optifine". Select it and click play. All of your glass blocks will be changed to look like in the first screenshot.

Comment: Good first answer! I took the liberty of formatting it a into a list to make it a bit easier to read. You can always [edit] it again if you don't like it. You could even roll back to a previous versions via the version history by clicking on "edited X ago".

Comment: It might be noteworthy that Optifine does change some other things as well, but most things can be turned off in the options menu if you only need the connected textures.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from texture pack possibilities, there are two different types of glass in the stock game -- [Glass](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Glass), and [Glass Pane](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Glass_Pane). One looks like a window with an outline, the other looks more like a wall of glass.

You can create 16x Glass Pane using 6x Glass and a [Crafting](http://minecraftpocketedition.wikia.com/wiki/Crafting_Table) Table.

Comment: Just to add to this: The Stained Glass varient ( http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Stained_Glass ) makes the glass less translucent, but also a softer look between borders.  The frosted varient as well is almost as clear as normal, but greatly hides the boards and whitestreaks though the glass itself.

Comment: This isn't really what the question is about - for reference, [this](https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/minecraft_gamepedia/images/5/5d/Glass_panels.png/revision/latest?cb=20110910155945) is what the glass panes mentioned in this answer look like.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what the question is about. It sounds like the OP is looking for glass panes fit together in one big window. Perhaps I'm wrong, but that's how I interpreted the question.

Answer (score 3):

I made this texture pack which works without Optifine, you could try it
https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/texture-packs/clear-glass-without-optifine